# Outlook Addin Documentation: Format of Location and EmailUser

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to sync values of location and attendees between Outlook Web event creation screen and my outlook Addin. In [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#location-stringlocation), as shown in screenshot attached below, type of location is given as String|**Location**.

[image: Doc Screenshot]

I clicked on the link of [**Location**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_7/office.location?view=office-js) and didn't find a description of type **Location** anywhere. In the documentation, **Location** is used as string, but the problem arise when I try to set a location from my addin to Location field of Outlook event screen. When I checked the value, I got it as shown below

[image: console]
I'm setting the value of location as

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.location.setAsync(emailAddress_to_add);
```

Same is the case for [EmailUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_7/office.emailuser?view=office-js) in case of Recipients/Attendees.

*Can anyone tell me the correct format, i.e. **Location** and **EmailUser**  in which I should set the location and attendees?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your location is just a string (not associated with an email address), you can use [location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item?view=office-js#location-stringlocation) APIs

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.location
```

In read mode, `location` is just a string property on `Office.context.mailbox.item`.

In compose mode, `location` returns an object of type [Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.location?view=office-js), on this object you can perform get/set operation.

If you want to set a location which has an associated email address, then you can make use of [EnhancedLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item?view=office-js#enhancedlocation-enhancedlocation) preview API.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.enhancedLocation
```

In read and compose mode, `enhancedlocation` will return an object of type [EnhancedLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.enhancedlocation?view=office-js), on which you can perform add/get/remove operation.

```
var locations = [
    {
        "id": "ConfRoom101@contoso.com",
        "type": Office.MailboxEnums.LocationType.Room
    }
];
Office.context.mailbox.item.enhancedLocation.addAsync(locations);
```